# Vscode with custom settings.xml Maven file per project in a workspace

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code

I have a Vscode workspace with a bunch of Maven projects, and which one has its own **Maven settings.xml** file.

As each project has its own settings file with the same name but in its own root folder I got success configuring both the workspace as each of the projects with such an option: `{"maven.executable.options": "-s my_settings.xml"}`.

Although, I can run successfully any of Maven commands for all projects, Vscode reports problems in the `pom.xml` files about missing artifacts and the same errors are reported when I run tests from the "Testing" in the Side Bar.

When I copy one of the project's settings file to the `~/.m2/settings.xml` that given project works fine, no errors at all.

So, I conclude Vscode doesn't respect the **"maven.executable.options"** for all of project operations inside IDE, like tests and maybe others operations but only for directly launched Maven commands.

I don't want to merge all those `settings.xml` files into a big one in my local `~/.m2/settgins.xml` each time I have to open a given set of projects.

Is there a way to teach Vscode to use different `settings.xml` for each project and make it work properly in all Vscode operations (not only Maven commands)?

Comment: I am curious: Why do you need many different `settings.xml`?

Comment: @JFabianMeier: I do not. But the projects need, they have lots of customization, like properties and tons of private repositories. And each project has tons of different configurations, and there are conflicting server tags among them, that's what make settings.xml merging a though and undesired task. However, they work like a charm in Netbeans. Netbeans respects the Maven arguments you set for each project, so when you launch the testing task all them are run with their own settings.xml seamlessly.

Comment: It is is more common to manage properties and configurations in the POM, and use a repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory to handle the armada of private repositories.

Comment: @JFabianMeier: I would be glad to have a way to ask Vscode: "Hey, use that `settings_abc.xml` for that project and not my `~/.m2/settings.xml`, Maven has that option, simply just allow me to set that option, like the classic Netbeans does.

Answer (score 9):

**VSCode setting ID**: `java.configuration.maven.userSettings`

1. In VSCode, go to Preferences > Settings > Workspace
2. Search 'maven'
3. Set 'Java > Configuration > Maven: User Settings' to `./settings.xml` to make VSCode use the local settings.xml of the project
4. Restart VSCode if needed

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCQSy.png)

Comment: I've set a custom settings.xml for both User and Workspace and restarted. Still goes for the ~/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: @paiego at the end I went for similar settings "Maven > Executable: Options (specifies default options for all mvn commands." and atted --s /path-to-my/settings.xml, unfortunatelly nothing else helped

Answer (score 0):

you can use
`mvn --settings settings.xml clean install`
to individually point respective settings.xml for each java app

Comment: I think you didn't get the question properly, watch out the `maven.executable.options` issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether the terminal executes the command "mvn ... -s my_settings.xml", which indicates the correctness of vscode-maven plugin. If so, the problem comes from the command itself.

A workaround is to delete the global maven settings.xml, typically in `$MAVEN_HOME\conf\settings.xml`. Then `mvn ... -s my_settings.xml` should work. It works fine for me.

The reason may be that when global maven settings file is found, mvn CLI may ignore the settings file in mvn option.